# Running jest tests from shell script - have failures cause script to exit

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, npm, jestjs

I have a plain package.json that runs [jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html) tests with `npm test` command. The relevant parts of the package.json look like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "test": "jest",
   "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "../shared/preprocessor.js"
  }
}
```

The shell script looks like so:

```
script_dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
parent_dir="$script_dir/.."

echo
echo "Running all tests..."
find "$parent_dir" -name package.json -maxdepth 2 -execdir npm test \;
```

Right now when a jest test fails, the bash script does not exit with a failure status. I would like it do so for the purposes of creating a CI loop with Jenkins. An example of a jest test failure is as follows:

```
 FAIL  js/components/__tests__/ExperienceCampaign-tests.js (13.19s)
● ExperienceCampaign › listening to ExperienceCampaignStore › it starts listening when the component is mounted
  - Expected: true toBe: false
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/experience-studio/campaign/js/components/__tests__/ExperienceCampaign-tests.js:54:26)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total)
Run time: 13.748s
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sadly, I just encountered the same problem. Did you manage to solve this yet, @i_trope?

Comment: Which version of jest are you using? I'm using 16.0.2 and am getting an exit status code of 1 when there are failing tests

Answer (score 3):

jest has a --forceExit flag that can be use to ... force exit :D.
just add it to your script.

You're probably doing some async thing in your test that doesn't return the callback in time. Might want to look closely at that.

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "test": "jest --forceExit",
   "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "../shared/preprocessor.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "npm test" command is executed for all results of the "find" command. The "find" doesn't really care if the test finished successfully or not.
From what I understand once the "npm test" command fails, all should stop.
Here is some code you could use instead of the "find":

```
for D in $(find "$parent_dir" -maxdepth 2 -name "package.json"); do
    ( cd ${F%/*} && npm test ) || exit $?
done
```